# Comparação de string

Tags: json, string, ruby, iterator

Problema : tenho que obter o objeto que apresenta o conteúdo no idioma inglês ( lang == en )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém dependendo da busca realizada a ordem dos idiomas vem completamente diferente e tentei criar um laço `obj.take['http://dbpedia.org/resource/HTML']['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment'].each` onde no escopo dessa iteração fazia uma comparação de string para obter o conteúdo no idioma inglês, mas surgiram vários problemas e mesmo tentando outros métodos que li no Stack En não consegui, então ficaria muito grato por uma eplicação. ( Fico muito perdido pra manusear json )

```
    obj.take['http://dbpedia.org/resource/HTML']['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment'].each do |i|

        # Obj contém todo o arquivo json que está representado na imagem

        # if ... aqui

        # obj.take['http://dbpedia.org/resource/HTML']['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment'][]['value']

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi bem sua pergunta, visto que neste JSON existe mais de um objeto com o valor de `lang`: `en`. Então fiz a função abaixo que procura recursivamente por todos os objetos que possuem a chave `lang` especificada.

Retorna uma array com estes objetos.

```
def deep_find_lang_entry(obj,lang, results = [])

    obj.keys.each do |key|
        if obj[key].is_a? Hash
            deep_find_lang_entry(obj[key], lang, results)
        elsif obj[key].is_a? Array
            obj[key].each do |item|
                deep_find_lang_entry(item, lang, results) if item.is_a? Hash
            end
        else
            results.push(obj) if key.eql?("lang") && obj[key].eql?(lang)
        end
    end

    results
end

#procura por todos que possuem a chave 'lang' com valor 'en'
objs_with_lang_eng = deep_find_lang_entry(obj, "en")

puts objs_with_lang_eng
#[
#   {
#       "type":"literal",
#       "value":"Life",
#       "lang":"en"
#   },
#   {
#       "type":"literal",
#       "value":"Life is a characteristic... of life, although many other sciences are involved.",
#       "lang":"en"
#   }
#   #, ...more#
# ]
```

Comment: Yay, funcionou ( só fiz algumas alterações ), muito obrigado.

Comment: @LuisSouza De nada! Boa sorte aí!

Answer (score 2):

O que apresento a seguir não é uma resposta à tua pergunta, mas penso que pode ser uma contribuição válida...
Vou usar um processador de json (linha de comando): http://trentm.com/json/.

1) Onde está a página dbpédia-Life?

```
curl http://dbpedia.org/data/Life.json > a.json
```

2) qual a descrição de "Life"?

```
cat a.json | 
json '["http://dbpedia.org/resource/Life"]["http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment"]' > b.json
```

3) filtrar a parte inglesa e extrair o `value`

```
cat b.json |  json  -c 'this.lang=="en"'  -a  value
```

finalmente juntando tudo:

```
curl http://dbpedia.org/data/Life.json |
  json '["http://dbpedia.org/resource/Life"]["http://www.....#comment"]' |
  json  -c 'this.lang=="en"'  -a value
```

dá o esperado: "Life is a characteristic distinguishing physical entities having biological processes (such as signaling and self-sustaining processes) from ....."

Já agora adivinhem o que daria (bash):

```
for a in Rio_de_Janeiro Braga London Paris Prague
  do 
    curl -q http://dbpedia.org/data/$a.json |   
     json "['http://dbpedia.org/resource/$a']['http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment']" | 
     json  -c 'this.lang=="pt"' -a value
  done > cidades.txt
```

Comment: Se for preciso instalar: instalar `node` e depois `sudo npm install -g json`

Comment: Super válido, muito obrigado.

Comment: @LuisSouza, obrigado eu.